# Invoking shell commands using os.system

Tags: python, system-calls

I am trying to use `os.system` to invoke an external (piped) shell command:

```
srcFile = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])

srcFileIdCmd = "echo -n '%s' | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1" % srcFile

print "ID command: %s" % srcFileIdCmd

srcFileID = os.system(srcFileIdCmd)

print "File ID: %s" % srcFileID
```

outputs

```
ID command: echo -n '/my/path/filename' | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1
File ID: 0
```

But when I run

```
echo -n '/my/path/filename' | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

manually on a command line, I get `2379496500`, not 0.

What do I need to change to get the correct value out of the shell command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(["program", "arg"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

instead, and then read from the file `sp.stdout`.  The pogram in question can be a shell, and you can pass complex shell commands to it as parameters (`["/usr/bin/bash", "-c", "my-complex-command"]`).

Comment: what do i plug in instead of `"program", "arg"`?

Comment: Whichever command you want to invoke, and as arguments you can plug in any list of command-line arguments.

Comment: what i got out of stdout is `<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x10b4a8300>`

Comment: `sp.stdout` is not the result. It's the file handle for the output from your command. You need to read the output from that file.